# Print next value of select in javascript

Tags: javascript, select

I have a `<select>` element with units of lengt in it. I have writen a javascript code, that should have printed the next value of the select, but it just sleects the next and prints the current one.
`var select = document.form.unit; var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex++].value; document.form.output.value = value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used post increment on `selectedIndex`. That's why variable `value` stores value of selected item. Modify your code to this:

```
var select = document.form.unit;
select.selectedIndex++;
var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
document.form.output.value = value;
```

Comment: I tried a little bit and it only worked for me, when i did "[select.selectedIndex].value" but anyways, thanks so much ^^